# Is any r.v. standard Gaussian up to reparametrization?

Tags: random-variables, change-of-variable, gaussian

I propose this exercise. Is it true, that given a real r.v. $X$ with a generic (continuous) p.d.f., there is always a real function $f$, s.t. $f(X) \sim N(0,1)$ where $N$ is a standard gaussian function ?

Than same question, in the multivariate case. For example, given $X_i,i=1...N$ r.v., is there always a non-linear transformation $Y_j=f_j(\{X_i\}_{i=1...N}),j=1,...,N$ such that the $Y_j$ are (multidimensional) standard Gaussian ?

This is a question I created during my self-study journey :)

PS: I think it is true but I wanted to check if I am wrong hence the question

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Answer (score 2):

If on its support $X$ has CDF strictly increasing $F$ of inverse $F^{-1}$, take $f(x)=\Phi^{-1}(F(x))$. Then$$P(f(X)\le y)=P(X\le F^{-1}(\Phi(y)))=\Phi(y)\implies f(X)\sim N(0,\,1).$$

Comment: Great! To complete the answer, does the same technique hold for the multidimensional case?

Comment: @Thomas Variational auto-encoders are an empirical demonstration that you can map most distributions to a multi-dimensional normal. I too would be interested to know if there is a formal proof of this.

Comment: @becko thanks for your comment and interest happy that you like the question :)

Comment: FYI I put a bounty for whoever wants to tuckle the multidimensional case :)

Comment: Stated another way:  the CDF is a way to reparameterize any continuous distribution to uniform$ [0,1]$.  Use this twice, go from your distribution to uniform [0,1], then from there to standard Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

1. It can not be true in general. For counterexample, let $X_1\sim U(0,1)$ distribution, and $X_2=X_1$. Then there can not be functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $f_1(X_1)$ and $f_2(X_2)$ that are i.i.d standard normal. You can see that by taking two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $f_1^{-1}(A)$ and $f_2^{-1}(B)$ are disjoint and
   $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_1^{-1}(A))\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_2^{-1}(B))>0$.

Details: First note that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equal almost everywhere then there is nothing to prove. So we assume that $f_1\neq f_2$ on a set of positive measure.

Now let me first show that: There are $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1^{-1}(A)$ and $f_2^{-1}(B)$ are disjoint and
$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_1^{-1}(A))\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_2^{-1}(B))>0$.

Take any two sets $A$ and $B$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_1^{-1}(A))=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_2^{-1}(B))>0$, and write $A':=f_1^{-1}(A)\cap f_2^{-1}(B)^c$ and $B':=f_2^{-1}(B)\cap f_1^{-1}(A)^c$. Clearly $f_1(A')\cap f_2(B')$ is empty. Now, either the firt scenario happens, that is $\mathbb{P}(X_1  \in f_1^{-1}(A'))\mathbb{P}(X_1  \in f_1^{-1}(B'))>0$, in which case we are done or the second scenario happens: $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_1^{-1}(A))=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_2^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_1^{-1}(A) \cap f_2^{-1}(B))$. If the second scenario happens we choose another pair of $A,B$. If the second scenario occurs for all $A,B$ then $f_1=f_2$ almost surely, otherwise we will have the first scenario.

Coming to the main problem: after choosing such a pair $A,B$, assume that $f_1(X_1)$ and $f_2(X_2)$ are independent. Then using independence
$$
\mathbb{P}(f_1(X_1) \in A, f_2(X_2) \in B)  =\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_1^{-1}(A))\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in f_2^{-1}(B)), 
$$
but by our choice of $A,B$, the left side is $0$ and the right side is positive.

2. It is true if $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent (but not necesserily identically distributed) random variables, and $X_i$ has strictly increasing CDF $F_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Then following J.G's answer take the $f_i(x)=\Phi^{-1}(F_i(x))$ and then

$$
\mathbb{P}(f_1(X_1)\leq y_1,\ldots,f_n(X_n)\leq y_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(f_i(X_i)\leq y_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n\Phi(y_i).
$$
Therefore $f_i(X_i)$'s are i.i.d normal.

Comment: Perfect. Maybe can you make more explicit the argument in 1 ? Anyway you analyzed it looks two limit cases, one where there is perfect correlation/collinearity/dependence, and the other where the variables are independent. I have the feeling that the statement "in-between" can still be true under some conditions. This feeling comes from the fact that PCA fails for perfect collinearity (singular matrix), but it works as soon as the correlation matrix is invertible. There may be some similar condition also for this nonlinear setting ?

Comment: Anyway, if there are no further contributions before the end of the bounty period, I will award it to you, even if these questions remained open, for the moment +1  ;)

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the proof for the case when $X_i$'s are independent but not necessarily identically distributed. It might still be possible to relax the independence but let me think more and get back here. The thing is that the probability space where the $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are defined (assume they are dependent) has to be "large enough" to "accommodate" $n$- independent normal random variable. I will edit the answer if I have more thoughts, and in any case, will add some more details to point 1 tomorrow. Best.